# Check if code is on master branch before release to production

Tags: azure-devops

I have a project with two branches (develop and master) and a release process to three environments (dev, staging, production).

I've implemented CI/CD, where the code on develop branch is the code deployed to dev and staging environments. The last step of my release pipeline is deploy to production and I would like to know if there's a way (a task) to check if the code deployed on dev and staging environment is already on master branch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case i would suggest you separate dev deployment from the rest, otherwise you will never know if your merge to master was succesful or not, since you never test it. In my opinion the master branch in your case should be the mirror on what is in production.

- for your dev build, create a release pipeline which deploys to your dev environment
- create another build for the master branch trigered When you merge your dev branch into master. You can use tagging and set a new tag on master, before merging, in order to preserve the old version for hotfixing. and then:

  1. either a new release pipeline with stages staging and Prod
  2. or a new artifact in the previous pipeline with artifact filters for the stages staging and prod

You could also consider changing your branching strategy. In case you develop features and only merge them to your branch, which is deployed to Prod in the end stage, you could use [Release Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/devops-at-microsoft/release-flow) branching model with only 1 branch.

Answer (score 0):

> The last step of my release pipeline is deploy to production and I
>   would like to know if there's a way (a task) to check if the code
>   deployed on dev and staging environment is already on master branch.

For now we don't have any task which is designed to do this kind of job. So there doesn't exist one easy solution to your requirements, you may have to do some changes to your workflow to meet your requirements. Just as the **Mario** suggests above, you can consider using the [Release Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/devops-at-microsoft/release-flow).